# parse json data in template Google App engine python

Tags: json, google-app-engine, templates, python-2.7

I am storing json data in the database in my google app engine, There is no problem in stroing the data to DB, But I am not sure how to parse it in the view, For e.g I get all the topics from my MODEL and pass it to the view which is using webapps template (I am not sure its django or jinja2 but it is the default provided by GAE), now my Model objext has one atribute which contains json, I want to parse this json in view without javascript as I am passing the object via template, can any one suggest me how to do it.

for e.g. I query the app engine as

```
topics = Topic.all()
//topic have many attributes including an attribute tags which contains json string
//["test", "somekeyword"]
```

I parse this string as individual tags in my view, Can I manipulate this list of objects in python to store as disctionary instead of tags when I retrieve it ? or is there a way to convert it to dictionary in django ?

P.S: I cant parse the json in my handler as the model will have multiple entries and parsing and storing these entries will be difficult

Comment: The right thing to do would be to parse it in your handler.  Can you show why it will be difficult to parse?  Using python's json module, parsing is a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

The webapp template language is Django (by default a rather old version). I think you have to change your requirements -- you can parse JSON in Python or in Javascript, but the Django template language is (intentionally) too weak to do that.  Maybe show us some samples of the data you want to work with?

Comment: Hi, I have just edited the question to add some details. Please see now